# Invite friends with promo code on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, invite

I want to put the invitation feature into my application. The invitation will be like this.
A user will invite a friend to apply via his / her email address. There will be one code in the mail address (like "B2C8S21A").

The person who receives the invitation will get 100 credits, for example, when they enter the code in the app.

How can I do this with firebase?

Answer (score 2):

[Firebase Invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/) makes it easy to turn your app's users into your app's strongest advocates.

Firebase Invites builds on Firebase Dynamic Links, which ensures that recipients of links have the best possible experience for their platform and the apps they have installed.

It is also possible to reward users for sharing the app, as described in the [best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/best-practices) section of the Invites documenation.

Comment: i don't understand dynamic links How can I generate a promo code